# How to create custom input/output functions in Microsoft graph (excel) api?

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Microsoft graph api with excel.
I have a spreadsheet with pre-filled data and some calculations.

For Example :

- Cells A1 to A10 has some data
- Cell B1 is an input field
- Cell C1 is an output field whose value is a functions of A:1 to A:10
  and B1 `ex: C1 = SUM(A1:A10)/B1`

Is is possible to use Microsoft graph API(or any other api) to send the input data in the form on HTTP request parameter and get the result as the response of the request ?

An Ideal request-response would look something like :

```
http://path-to-workbook/path-to-response-data?parameterB1=someNumericValue 
Response:
{
  C1: <result of calculation>
}
```

Is there a way to achieve such functionality useing graph API ?

Anything similar or helpful response/resources will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the update [range](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/range_update) api if your need simple logic, set the **formula** in request body to  **= SUM(A1:A10)/B1**

If you need Complex IO processing, Graph API for excel is not intent to I/O operation except the Report now, so you need to submit an feature request in the [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) for this.

Actually, there are a possible API in Graph(Just idea, not test this), it is the OneDrive API, while you modify the Excel file, send the data to a custom NET api service to calculate and then use the Drive api [update the file](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/driveitem_update)

Comment: SUM(A1:A10)/B1 is an example.. the actual formula will be much complicated i need it to be taken from the spreadsheet itself.

Comment: So you can replace the demo formula with the actual one. And donot forget to use the Auto-Fill or other way to apply the formula to the entire column. Graph API doesn't provide the way to auto-fill now.

Comment: Yes I can do that .But the problem here is I am not working with single formula 
or a single set of data here. I have several intertwined operations. The point of the question is to find out weather it is possible to use Graph API as an I/O operation. Ex : I need it take my input to cell B1 and respond with whatever the output will be on C1.